# Write a list to columns

Tags: python

I have a Python list of data:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to read this data into a file as a column in the following way:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and then I want my next list `([6,7,8,9,10])` to be added to it (with a tab):

```
1 6  
2 7  
3 8  
4 9  
5 10
```

and so on.

Could anyone help me with how I can do this please?

Comment: read this data into a file or write this to a file?

Comment: Sorry - write it to a file. Edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the built-in function [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
    for x in zip(*lst):
        f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n".format(*x))
```

**output:**

```
1   6   11

2   7   12

3   8   13

4   9   14

5   10  15
```

Comment: Okay great, thank you. In my actual code, I am looping, and creating list after list, that needs to be added to the data.txt file each time. Is there an easy way to add as I loop?

Comment: @user1551817 better create a list of lists first,and in the end using `zip()` write them to the file. it'll require lesser IO operations so it'll be faster.

Answer (score 4):

```
col1,col2 = [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]

>>> output = '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,row)) for row in zip(col1,col2))
>>> print(output)
1       6
2       7
3       8
4       9
5       10
```

To write to a file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

Comment: And Now how can find minimum of first column nad its relevant of second column. I mean the minimum of first column is 1 and its relevant in second column is 6.

Comment: Ethan: you may benefit from a computer science course. Printing of data (to files or console) is entirely separate from analysis and computation of data, in the same way that writing letters is different from literature, and thus irrelevant. The answer to your question can be found by googling how to find the argmax, either an algorithm (do it once) or a data structure (do it many times). Algorithm is brute force (i.e. a for loop, or reduce, or sort). Or more advanced: keep a data structure (e.g. priority queue or list) in sorted order by 'key' and look it up by key (myQueue.getMin()).

Comment: E.g. `xyPairs = [[1,2],[3,4]]` `maxYPair = sorted(xyPairs, key=lambda xy:xy[1])[-1]` `argmaxY = maxYPair[0]`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of all these lists, like

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

you can transpose it with `zip(*data)` to get

```
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

and then write these out with something like

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    for row in zip(*data):
        f.write('\t'.join(row)+'\n')
```

Comment: you need a `\n` too, else everything will write to a single line.

Comment: you will not be able to write to your file because you did not open it in write-mode

Comment: Thank you as well. I need to remember to always test my solutions before posting.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> with open('in.txt') as f:
...    input = [s.strip() for s in f.readlines()]
...
>>> input
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> combine = ['6','7','8','9','10']
>>> with open('out.txt','w') as f:
...     for x in izip(input,combine):
...         f.write("{0}\t{1}\n".format(x[0],x[1]))
...
>>> quit()
burhan@sandbox:~$ cat out.txt
1       6
2       7
3       8
4       9
5       10
```

Comment: Could you find the minimum od x[0] and its relevant x[1]?
I mean I need to know which is the minimum in x[0] and what is the value for x[1]. here is 1, 6